How to replace illegal xml characters when casting string to XML in SQL? Only illegal characters in values not badges or attributes?
I have an SQL procedure which gets an input parameter @metadata nvarchar(max). This string is serialized from C# object. When I try to cast it as XML I get an error "illegal xml" character.
For reasons it would be way simpler for me if I could correct this in the procedure not in C# code. Is there a way to replace those illegal characters in the procedure?
Mainly the problems are "<" and ">". Because replacing those characters also screws up the xml badges in string. Is there a way to replace those characters only inside values not badges or attributes?
I tried:
SET @metadata = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@metadata, CHAR(0), ''), '&', '&amp;'), '"', '&quot;'), '''', '&apos;'), '>', '&gt;'), '<', '&lt;');
But obviously this approach messes with badges of an xml and also " in attributes of badges.
Any suggestions?

You'd need to give a [mcve] because only the NUL character (char 0) needs to be removed, the other characters are encoded automatically https://dbfiddle.uk/RfeGexqy
